# TYPO3 Fluid adds \ufeff after body tag?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I am using TYPO3 7.6.4 and I have just converted an existing site to a fluid template system. I now have a blank line at the top of the page. Checking the source code I see a \ufeff character there (See question mark):

```
<body id="uid10" class="pid11">
?<div id="body">
```

How do I remove this character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your templates contains [Byte Order Mark character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (a.k.a. `U+FEFF`, `BOM`), probably this one file which starts with `<div id="body">`.

You didn't mention which OS and IDE you are using, so can't give you ready-to-use recipe, but just google it for something like "*how will I remove BOM from file in [your OS] and [your editor]*".

Note that advanced IDEs i.e. like PhpStorm has utils for finding and removing BOMs in files. (*this is not a spam, just my experience*)

Comment: Great thanks, this same problem actually solved another  issue I was having with a disappearing/reappearing  page... I use Notepadd++ and just converted all my files to UTF-8 without BOM.